# Nested SVG element not respecting height

Tags: svg

I'm fairly new to SVG, so probably making an obvious mistake here.

I'm trying to get the nested #custom_logo element to respect the height and width attributes I've given it. My understanding is that by setting the viewBox's height to 300 I've defined the height of the canvas to be 300 units. This should mean that setting the height of the nested element to 300 i.e 100% of the height.

The element doesn't seem to care what I set its height and width to however - they have no impact on the rendering.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 600 300" width="600" height="300">
  <defs id="SvgjsDefs1001"/>
  <svg id="SvgjsSvg1002" width="2" height="0" style="overflow: hidden; top: -100%; left: -100%; position: absolute; opacity: 0">
    <polyline id="SvgjsPolyline1003" points="0,0"/>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1004" d="M0 0 "/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="custom_logo" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" width="297.583909163781" height="300">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M54.218,29.063c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    S53.198,29.063,54.218,29.063z M54.218,37.232c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C52.371,36.405,53.198,37.232,54.218,37.232z M44.416,12.726c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C42.569,11.899,43.396,12.726,44.416,12.726z M54.218,53.569    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C52.371,52.742,53.198,53.569,54.218,53.569z M54.218,12.726c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C52.371,11.899,53.198,12.726,54.218,12.726z M54.218,45.401c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S53.198,45.401,54.218,45.401z M73.823,45.401c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S72.803,45.401,73.823,45.401z M64.021,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C62.174,52.742,63.001,53.569,64.021,53.569z M64.021,29.063    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S63.001,29.063,64.021,29.063z     M83.625,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C81.779,52.742,82.605,53.569,83.625,53.569z M73.823,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C71.976,52.742,72.803,53.569,73.823,53.569z M64.021,37.232c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C62.174,36.405,63.001,37.232,64.021,37.232z M64.021,45.401    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S63.001,45.401,64.021,45.401z     M54.218,20.895c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C52.371,20.068,53.198,20.895,54.218,20.895z M24.811,45.401c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S23.791,45.401,24.811,45.401z M34.613,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C32.766,52.742,33.593,53.569,34.613,53.569z M34.613,45.401    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S33.593,45.401,34.613,45.401z     M24.811,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C22.964,52.742,23.791,53.569,24.811,53.569z M15.008,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C13.162,52.742,13.989,53.569,15.008,53.569z M90.098,60.348c-0.501-0.451-1.23-0.548-1.833-0.244    c-7.634,3.858-16.75,3.858-24.385-0.002c-0.269-0.136-0.567-0.182-0.86-0.16c-0.514-0.05-1.003,0.143-1.34,0.5    c-3.577,1.675-7.522,2.568-11.47,2.568c-0.002,0-0.005,0-0.005,0c-0.07,0-0.137,0.012-0.204,0.021    c-0.068-0.009-0.134-0.021-0.204-0.021c-0.002,0-0.003,0-0.005,0c-3.944,0-7.886-0.891-11.47-2.568    c-0.336-0.356-0.822-0.549-1.334-0.501c-0.295-0.024-0.595,0.023-0.866,0.161c-7.634,3.859-16.75,3.86-24.315,0.04    c-0.598-0.342-1.349-0.271-1.873,0.178c-0.524,0.449-0.71,1.179-0.463,1.824l10.619,27.773c0.242,0.633,0.849,1.051,1.526,1.051    h28.181c0.07,0,0.137-0.012,0.205-0.021c0.068,0.009,0.135,0.021,0.205,0.021h28.181c0.677,0,1.284-0.418,1.526-1.051    l10.619-27.773C90.772,61.513,90.599,60.8,90.098,60.348z M22.739,87.7l-8.846-23.136c7.141,2.496,15.046,2.233,22.033-0.774    L40.849,87.7H22.739z M50.205,87.7c-0.07,0-0.137,0.012-0.205,0.021c-0.068-0.009-0.135-0.021-0.205-0.021h-5.611l-4.792-23.276    c3.326,1.213,6.861,1.854,10.398,1.854c0.002,0,0.004,0,0.006,0c0.07,0,0.136-0.012,0.204-0.021    c0.068,0.008,0.134,0.021,0.204,0.021c0.002,0,0.004,0,0.006,0c3.543,0,7.083-0.643,10.398-1.852L55.816,87.7H50.205z     M77.262,87.7h-18.11l4.923-23.911c6.987,3.009,14.892,3.271,22.033,0.775L77.262,87.7z M44.416,29.063    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S43.396,29.063,44.416,29.063z M44.416,37.232    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C42.569,36.405,43.396,37.232,44.416,37.232z M44.416,20.895c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C42.569,20.068,43.396,20.895,44.416,20.895z M34.613,37.232c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C32.766,36.405,33.593,37.232,34.613,37.232z M44.416,45.401    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S43.396,45.401,44.416,45.401z M34.613,29.063    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S33.593,29.063,34.613,29.063z     M44.416,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C42.569,52.742,43.396,53.569,44.416,53.569z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <text id="SvgjsText1007" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" x="307.583909163781" y="27.1015625" svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}">Heading</text>
  <text id="SvgjsText1008" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" x="307.583909163781" y="43.1015625" svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}">Slogan</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: What element(s) that doesn't seem to care about the width and height setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that by setting the viewBox's height to 300 I've defined the height of the canvas to be 300 units.

No.  You're telling the browser that the elements in the SVG occupy the area from 0 to 300. But, in fact, the icon was only occupying the area from 0 to 100.  The browser had no way of knowing that you wanted it scaled up 3x.

> This should mean that setting the height of the nested element to 300 i.e 100% of the height.

Setting the width and height of the inner `<svg>` will not make it scale to fit the parent SVG if the inner SVG does not have a `viewBox` attribute.  The icon is approx 100x100, so an appropriate `viewBox` would be:

```
viewBox="0 0 100 100"
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 600 300" width="600" height="300">
  <defs id="SvgjsDefs1001"/>
  <svg id="SvgjsSvg1002" width="2" height="0" style="overflow: hidden; opacity: 0">
    <polyline id="SvgjsPolyline1003" points="0,0"/>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1004" d="M0 0 "/>
  </svg>
  <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="custom_logo" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" width="297.583909163781" height="300">
    <g>
      <g>
        <path d="M54.218,29.063c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    S53.198,29.063,54.218,29.063z M54.218,37.232c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C52.371,36.405,53.198,37.232,54.218,37.232z M44.416,12.726c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C42.569,11.899,43.396,12.726,44.416,12.726z M54.218,53.569    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C52.371,52.742,53.198,53.569,54.218,53.569z M54.218,12.726c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C52.371,11.899,53.198,12.726,54.218,12.726z M54.218,45.401c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S53.198,45.401,54.218,45.401z M73.823,45.401c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S72.803,45.401,73.823,45.401z M64.021,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C62.174,52.742,63.001,53.569,64.021,53.569z M64.021,29.063    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S63.001,29.063,64.021,29.063z     M83.625,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C81.779,52.742,82.605,53.569,83.625,53.569z M73.823,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C71.976,52.742,72.803,53.569,73.823,53.569z M64.021,37.232c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C62.174,36.405,63.001,37.232,64.021,37.232z M64.021,45.401    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S63.001,45.401,64.021,45.401z     M54.218,20.895c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C52.371,20.068,53.198,20.895,54.218,20.895z M24.811,45.401c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S23.791,45.401,24.811,45.401z M34.613,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C32.766,52.742,33.593,53.569,34.613,53.569z M34.613,45.401    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S33.593,45.401,34.613,45.401z     M24.811,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C22.964,52.742,23.791,53.569,24.811,53.569z M15.008,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C13.162,52.742,13.989,53.569,15.008,53.569z M90.098,60.348c-0.501-0.451-1.23-0.548-1.833-0.244    c-7.634,3.858-16.75,3.858-24.385-0.002c-0.269-0.136-0.567-0.182-0.86-0.16c-0.514-0.05-1.003,0.143-1.34,0.5    c-3.577,1.675-7.522,2.568-11.47,2.568c-0.002,0-0.005,0-0.005,0c-0.07,0-0.137,0.012-0.204,0.021    c-0.068-0.009-0.134-0.021-0.204-0.021c-0.002,0-0.003,0-0.005,0c-3.944,0-7.886-0.891-11.47-2.568    c-0.336-0.356-0.822-0.549-1.334-0.501c-0.295-0.024-0.595,0.023-0.866,0.161c-7.634,3.859-16.75,3.86-24.315,0.04    c-0.598-0.342-1.349-0.271-1.873,0.178c-0.524,0.449-0.71,1.179-0.463,1.824l10.619,27.773c0.242,0.633,0.849,1.051,1.526,1.051    h28.181c0.07,0,0.137-0.012,0.205-0.021c0.068,0.009,0.135,0.021,0.205,0.021h28.181c0.677,0,1.284-0.418,1.526-1.051    l10.619-27.773C90.772,61.513,90.599,60.8,90.098,60.348z M22.739,87.7l-8.846-23.136c7.141,2.496,15.046,2.233,22.033-0.774    L40.849,87.7H22.739z M50.205,87.7c-0.07,0-0.137,0.012-0.205,0.021c-0.068-0.009-0.135-0.021-0.205-0.021h-5.611l-4.792-23.276    c3.326,1.213,6.861,1.854,10.398,1.854c0.002,0,0.004,0,0.006,0c0.07,0,0.136-0.012,0.204-0.021    c0.068,0.008,0.134,0.021,0.204,0.021c0.002,0,0.004,0,0.006,0c3.543,0,7.083-0.643,10.398-1.852L55.816,87.7H50.205z     M77.262,87.7h-18.11l4.923-23.911c6.987,3.009,14.892,3.271,22.033,0.775L77.262,87.7z M44.416,29.063    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S43.396,29.063,44.416,29.063z M44.416,37.232    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C42.569,36.405,43.396,37.232,44.416,37.232z M44.416,20.895c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847    s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C42.569,20.068,43.396,20.895,44.416,20.895z M34.613,37.232c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847    c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847C32.766,36.405,33.593,37.232,34.613,37.232z M44.416,45.401    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S43.396,45.401,44.416,45.401z M34.613,29.063    c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847s-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847c-1.02,0-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847S33.593,29.063,34.613,29.063z     M44.416,53.569c1.02,0,1.847-0.827,1.847-1.847c0-1.02-0.827-1.847-1.847-1.847s-1.847,0.827-1.847,1.847    C42.569,52.742,43.396,53.569,44.416,53.569z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <text id="SvgjsText1007" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" x="307.583909163781" y="27.1015625" svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}">Heading</text>
  <text id="SvgjsText1008" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" x="307.583909163781" y="43.1015625" svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}">Slogan</text>
</svg>
```

As an aside, the style properties `top`, `left`, and `position` are HTML style properties.  They have no effect in a nested SVG element.